# How to write a REST API?

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, rest

I'm writing an iPhone app as a hobby project and it will need a web service to provide it with data. It's not very different from what I do at work, but at work I only write views and controllers. Someone else is responsible for writing the model and usually the clients provide the web service.

I have done some web programming before, back when everyone were using MySQL and PHP, so my skills are a bit outdated, but I'm confident that I would be able to pull it of using the techniques I already know. However, I don't want to waste my time using obsolete tools. I've figured out that the state of the art would be to write a REST API. I was thinking that there should be some pretty good frameworks out there that pretty much just gives you a REST API with CRUD functionality as soon as you've defined a model.

I guess my question is: What would be the fastest way to get a REST API up and running? I really just want to focus on writing the iPhone app and not spend too much time on this API. It would be great if I could get web administration and revision history too. I should also add that the API isn't supposed to be public, so support for authentication would be great as well.

Just to be clear. I wouldn't mind a PHP framework. In fact it could possibly be better since I know that my current hosting supports it.

Comment: REST is probably not what you really want: https://medium.com/@trevorhreed/you-re-api-isn-t-restful-and-that-s-good-b2662079cf0e

Comment: You could use [this 66 line PHP script](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api/blob/master/extras/core.php) I wrote.

Comment: Answered 5 years later 8-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to let you know:

I ended up using Ruby on Rails.

**EDIT:** Since this answer has been downvoted for not providing the reason behind choosing Ruby on Rails and also no instructions on how to write a REST API with it, I thought I would give you my motivation and some simple instructions.

I started reading a book about Ruby on Rails and realized that all I needed to do was to use scaffolding and I got a JSON REST API for free.

Here's a good guide to get you started: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

When you have your Ruby on Rails environment up and running, creating your REST API isn't harder than running:

```
$ rails generate scaffold Post name:string title:string content:text
```

(Example from the above link.) I also found that Rails is very easy and free to deploy to [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/), which meant that I didn't have to pay for hosting for my very basic, low traffic, REST API. There are many other reasons why I am very happy to work with Ruby on Rails, but that's beyond the context of this question.

Comment: giving yourself an answer and then giving it a checkmark  bad form man VERY bad form.

Comment: @thenetimp There's nothing bad about answering your own question. In fact it's encouraged, as long as it's a correct answer and it hasn't been given by anyone else. You don't gain any rep for accepting your own answer, so I really don't see what you could possibly have against it.

Comment: it'd be better if you gave your reasoning for choosing it

Comment: @mustafa, I just updated my answer with my reasoning for choosing it.

Comment: @Nate I would recommend Ruby on Rails to anyone wanting to write a REST API, so I will not delete my answer. However, I read your feedback and updated my answer. I hope it pleases you.

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @DennisKrøger if the question is "How to write a REST api?" then "I used RoR. Here's a guide to get started on their scaffolding" is totally a proper answer.

Answer (score 42):

**EDIT:**

The links below which apparently were good for 3 years are no longer working so I went and found a couple of new tutorials that I think are going to stick around for a while. These are on the Ray Wenderlich site, a very well respected ios dev tutorial site. The first article actually references the broken links below but it is complete within itself:

[How To Write A Simple PHP/MySQL Web Service for an iOS App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app)

and the second one has a little twist to it. It used parse.com on the backend and AFNetworking. Both of which are quite excellent.

[How To Synchronize Core Data with a Web Service – Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1)

---

I have fixed the broken links below by finding the articles in the way back machine. People seem to like the links so I will keep them. The links above should provide more food for thought.

---

I am doing exactly the same thing with my iphone app. I found this article on building a RESTful API in PHP:

https://web.archive.org/web/20130910164802/http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/

and there is also a followup article here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20130323001500/http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/making-restful-requests-in-php/

with a link to source code at the bottom of the article.

Comment: These links seem like they're timing out now.  If that's happening for anyone else I'm not sure.  :/

Answer (score 8):

I have programmed a REST API in [ZEND Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) using the Zend_Rest_Controller, on the iPhone I used [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). My experience with both where good. At the beginning I had some trouble setting up ZEND and connecting it to mySQL, but once I figured out how to do it I was able to write the API very quickly. I can share more information with you if you have any further questions.

EDIT: There seems to be no official documentation on `Zend_Rest_Controller`. [This link](http://techchorus.net/create-restful-applications-using-zend-framework) describes how to use it to create your API. You simply have to disable rendering in the `init()` of your subclass and implement the methods for each REST call.

Comment: I don't see any ZEND_Rest_Controller on Zend site. I see ZEND_Rest_Server. Is this the one you talking about?

Comment: Have a look here for a good start on how to use zend_rest_controller: http://techchorus.net/create-restful-applications-using-zend-framework .creating a rest api is effortless with this class

Comment: This seems to be more or less exactly what I need. I'll try it out and if I'm successful I'll accept this as my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I guess he wasn't successful... :D

Answer (score 8):

I followed a quite simple tutorial for creating RESTful APIs with PHP:

[Corey Maynard - Creating a RESTful API with PHP](http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/api/v1/example)

The main concept includes:

- one abstract class that handles the parsing of the URI and returning the response, and
- one concrete class that consists of just the endpoints for the API.

Answer (score 3):

What about Python?

I'd use Python, Django and Piston.

1. I'd generate Django models from your
   existent DB using [inspectdb](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/#auto-generate-the-models).
2. Add the [Django admin](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/) to your models.
3. Add [Django Piston](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Home) to your app.
4. Profit.

With no experience with Python or Django probably it'll take you a day to develop this solution and all code is unit tested and [proved to work](http://urbanairship.com/).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use PHP I recommend using the CodeIgniter framework with Phil Sturgeon's REST server:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2

https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the following PHP class that follows MVC.
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5080-PHP-Implement-REST-Web-services-servers.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I strongly discourage using **anything** from phpclasses.org. Many classes on that site are untested, insecure, written by script kiddies. Look somewhere more reputable like PEAR or Zend

Comment: Over 3000 PHP developers submitted packages to the PHPClasses site. Some are much more capable than others. Many are even also contributors of PEAR and Zend. Telling people to not use a package distributed in that site just because you found some packages that you say are untested and insecure, is pure prejudice. The package recommened by @src happens to be a top rated package. It would have been wiser if you looked at the package code or at least the user ratings before you decided to generalize against everything just because it is distributed in the site.

Answer (score 0):

You should use whatever languages you are comfortable with for the web service. Any language that can formulate REST responses to requests is fine.

That said, if you want to get something running quickly, I suggest using Python on Google App Engine. It's free and you can use Java instead of Python if you so desire. App Engine supports authentication using OpenID and/or Google Accounts (not sure if they're mutually exclusive) so that should make things easier to code.

As far as making the requests on the iOS device, I suggest using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).

Answer (score 0):

If you already know PHP, there's nothing wrong with a PHP/MySQL backend.   You can send all responses in iPhone-compatible plist xml format, and instantly turn the response into a NSDictionary/NSArray/NSNumber data structure with this short snippet of code:

```
NSString *response = [request responseString];
NSData* plistData = [response dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSString *errorStr;
NSDictionary* plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistData 
                                                       mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable 
                                                                 format:&format 
                                                       errorDescription:&errorStr];
```

I also use the ASIHTTP package for forming URLs, sending asynchronous requets, and receiving the responses, I highly recommend it:

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Answer (score 0):

Another option is restSQL, an ultra-lightweight persistence framework. See http://restsql.org. It supports MySQL and PostgreSQL and runs in a standard Java EE container, e.g. Apache Tomcat.

restSQL is a very unconventional data access layer. restSQL is not an object-oriented view of the database. It presents flat or hierarchical "views" of relational database tables. These views are query-able and updatable through a simple REST-based HTTP or Java API. The HTTP interface is based on REST principles, which use HTTP’s built-in features, rather than abstracting away from them.

You want a 'REST API with CRUD functionality' and that's exactly restSQL's sweet spot. You could do this with no code. Simply define your SQL Resources via XML files and start doing HTTP calls against them with full CRUD capability.