# Creating a Javascript Api Interface

Tags: php, javascript, api, interface

I'm currently working on a solution in php which queries an sql database. However, i want other website to be able to query the database (or the functions in php). I search google, but i can't find out how to expose these functions to javascript due to crossdomain policies(i think).

Anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [soap](http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/php/Creating_A_Web_Service_With_PHP_5%27s_SOAP_Extension.htm) or [rest](http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/).

If I understood right... if you want other sites to access your Database...
Obviously...use jQuery :p to make the calls

Answer (score 1):

If Cross-Domain is your only concern, check out [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). You can also check the [jsonp](/questions/tagged/jsonp) tag to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you're inadvertently writing a web API. REST is hot these days, for good reason (they play well with javascript clients, for one).

[Here is a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973156/how-to-write-a-rest-api) that should give you lots to chew on.

Answer (score 0):

you could build a rpc server (remote-procedure-call). It could be either xml-rpc or json-rpc.
[Here](http://www.google.ro/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=json%20rpc&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjson-rpc.org%2F&ei=BBALT5f7MZP64QTvmoizAg&usg=AFQjCNGFl7OmP75JWxLVl4Os6RMLjsJOMA) are some good documentations