# how to setup a cms as backend for android app?

Tags: php, android, api, joomla

I'm planned to develop  a mobile application using android as front end and JOOMLA as a back-end. Don't know how to connect with android. Could any one help me with this?? I had searched in many sites but couldn't get solution. http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database.
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=428656.

Please reply asap..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to write a service layer in your CMS. Then data which are required for the android app will be exposed as a data service from your Joomla CMS. Please check the link for more info.

[How to write a REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973156/how-to-write-a-rest-api)