# Joomla - Creating a web service that can consumed by a Windows Phone 8 App

Tags: joomla, windows-phone-8

I'm building a Windows Phone 8 app that needs to get data from a website that was built on Joomla I believe.

Is it possible to create a Webservice that my app can consume?

Or is there a better way?

The Joomla version is 2.5.9 I believe

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a service layer in your CMS. Then data which are required for the android app will be exposed as a data service from your Joomla CMS. Please check the link for more info.

[How to write a REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973156/how-to-write-a-rest-api)

Answer (score 0):

*Just in case you're not aware there is a range of critical bugs and exploits that have been fixed since 2.5.9. Your client should update to 2.5.16 ASAP as there is a well known exploit that can be used to effectively root the site in a matter of minutes.*

After updating, you could look at the [AJAX interface](https://github.com/Joomla-Ajax-Interface/component) that [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901680/betweenbrain) from [Between Brain](http://betweenbrain.com) created for most versions of Joomla (it's actually part of the core from 3.2 onwards).

That would be the simplest way to get started as it provides a path in that can be authenticated etc and extending it to other non-core extensions is relatively trivial.