# PHP API for android using mysql

Tags: php, android, json

So, currently i am using firebase for storing my app data online,
I would like to create my own database,
so i was planning to get a 100gb bandwidth hosting plan with php and mysql (is that bandwidth enought) per download, my app downloads approximately 0.4MB of data (as per firebase).

So, to create the api, i just have to encode the mysql data into json and print it ? then my android app will read it and use it ? is this the best method ?

```
$sth = mysqli_query("SELECT ...");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
```

or is there any other, more efficient method to do this ?

Comment: That makes sense to me.

Comment: `is this the best method` there is no best method, but it should work. `(is that bandwidth enought)` depends on how many users you will have, and how much data they will request. In other words - nobody knows

Comment: my data is 210kb, lets consider 400kb, 2000-4000 users per month, each user downloads 10 times lets say, that sums up to 15 gb i guess (considering higher end everywhere i guess)

Answer (score 1):

Yes but you should send response code like 200,403 as well.
here is a similar question

[How to write a REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973156/how-to-write-a-rest-api])