# link phpmyadmin database with expo react native

Tags: ios, database, react-native, phpmyadmin

hi I am new to react native but I wish to connect my iOS app with the phpmyadmin database anyone can share the idea how should I do. thanks a lot

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You mean MYSQL database. You can use PHP to create and serve a **REST API** which you can access from React Native with Fetch or Axios. I've done this on many IOS apps and web apps. You can also use existing frameworks or CMS systems that have a built in rest API, like Laravel or Wordpress.

Build your own:
[How to write a REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973156/how-to-write-a-rest-api)

Laravel:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources

Wordpress:
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

More on REST API's:
[What exactly is RESTful programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming)